# How do you create (via code) your own action bar

Tags: drupal

I have created my own custom module that display some data (as a table) and now I want to add nice action bar to it.

I was looking on examples and did not find any good (like on a screen below).

How do I do that (programatically)?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Did you make any research in core or contrib module code ?

Comment: @FKY I'm doing this right now, thought there is an API which I could not find.

Comment: I think it's an admin view , you can add bulk operation in view edition. So try to create an admin view and if you need to alter it do it by hooks